# Don't understand serialize()

Tags: php

I'm looking at this function: serialize() for PHP and I don't really understand what is it's function. Can someone provide a simple example with output?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Basically, the goal of [`serialize`](http://php.net/serialize) is to transform any *(alsmost)* kind of data to a string, so it can be transmitted, stored, ...

A quick example :

```
$my_array = array(
    'a' => 10,
    'glop' => array('test', 'blah'),
);
$serialized = serialize($my_array);
echo $serialized;
```

Will get you this output :

```
a:2:{s:1:"a";i:10;s:4:"glop";a:2:{i:0;s:4:"test";i:1;s:4:"blah";}}
```

And, later, you can [`unserialize`](http://php.net/unserialize) that string, to get the original data back :

```
$serialized = 'a:2:{s:1:"a";i:10;s:4:"glop";a:2:{i:0;s:4:"test";i:1;s:4:"blah";}}';
$data = unserialize($serialized);
var_dump($data);
```

Will get you :

```
array
  'a' => int 10
  'glop' => 
    array
      0 => string 'test' (length=4)
      1 => string 'blah' (length=4)
```

Common uses include :

- Ability to transmit *(almost)* any kind of PHP data from one PHP script to another
- Ability to store *(almost)* any kind of PHP data in a single database field -- even if it's not quite a good practice on the database-side, it can sometimes be usefull
- Ability to store data in some caching mecanism (APC, memcached, files, ...), in which you can only store strings

Note, though, that using `serialize` is great when you are only working with PHP *(as it's a PHP-specific format, that's able to work with almost any kind of PHP data, and is really fast)* ; but it's not that great when you have to also work with something else than PHP *(as it's PHP-specific)*. In those cases, you can use XML, JSON (see [`json_encode`](http://php.net/json_encode) and [`json_decode`](http://php.net/json_decode)), ...

In the PHP manual, you can also read the [Object Serialization](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.serialization.php) section, btw.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to save an array or object normalised in a database row for example, `serialize()` (and `unserialize()`) are your friends, because you can't store an array or object flattened without first turning it into a string.

`json_encode()` and `json_decode()` are similar except they encode as JSON.

Answer (score 0):

See [this example](http://www.ideone.com/4W7AvhgZ), should be pretty clear.